# Delete many elements of a list with del()

Tags: python, arrays, list, syntax-error

I know how to delete one element of a list but if I'm trying to delete many elements I get a syntax error but don't know why.

```
a=[[00],[01],[10],[11]]
b=[0,3]

[[del a[x]] for x in b]
```

so the result should looks like:

```
a = [[01],[10]]
```

Well thank you...I understand the problem...`del` changes the index of array `a` so I would be out of bounds! :)

Now another question refer to the question...
if I got `a`,`c` and I want to create `b`

```
a=[[00],[01],[10],[11]]
c=[[1],[2,3,4],[5,6],[7]]
```

I go in that way.

```
b = [i for i,el in enumerate(c) for item in el if len(el)<2]
```

and then I do this

```
a = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i not in b]
```

is there a simple way to do that? Creating `b` and then "deleting" the elements of `b` in `a` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[[00],[01],[10],[11]]
>>> b=[0,3]
>>> # b = set(b)
>>> a = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i not in b]
>>> a
[[1], [10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to delete items inplace, you can do this:

```
map(lambda i: a.pop(i), sorted(b, key=lambda i: -i))
```

or

```
for i in sorted(b, key=lambda x: -x):
    del a[i]
```

or

```
for i in sorted(b)[::-1]:
    del a[i]
```

You have to sort items in b before deletion, so you won't have `out of range` exception

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` has a pretty convenient way of deleting elements:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[00],[01],[10],[11]])
>>> b = np.array([0,3])
>>> a
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [10],
       [11]])
>>> b
array([0, 3])
>>> np.delete(a, b, axis=0)
array([[ 1],
       [10]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove elements from the end of the list, you will not get the Exception `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`, because when you delete an element, only those elements after it are affected :

```
>>> a=[[00],[01],[10],[11]]
>>> b=[0,3]
>>> for i in sorted(b, reverse=True):
...     del a[i]
...
>>> a
[[1], [10]]
```